# I Want To Create AN API Of Notifcation App

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, push-notification

I created a notification App by using the Django channels, Websockt and successfully sending notification to the Webscoketking.com. Now I want to create the API of this App for sending the notifications of the web site. I want to create an API for send the notifications on Frontend but it is successfullly sending notification on Websocketking.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import json
# Create your models here.

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    """Model class for users"""

    USER_CHOICES = [
        ('expert', 'Expert'),
        ('business', 'Business'),
        ('admin', 'Admin'),
    ]

    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False)
    confirm_password = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False)
    user_choices = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=USER_CHOICES, default='expert')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.email}"


class Notification(models.Model):
    account_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message = models.TextField()
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('saving notification')
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        notification_objs = Notification.objects.filter(is_read=False).count()
        data = {'count': notification_objs, 'current_notification': self.message}
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            "test_group", {
                "type": "send_notification",
                "value": json.dumps(data)
            }
        )
        super(Notification, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class AccountApproval(models.Model):
    account_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    approval_message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

COnsumers.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
import json

class TestConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.room_name = "test"
        self.room_group_name = "test_group"
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )
        self.accept()
        print("connected")
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'status': 'connected Through Django Channels'}))

    def receive(self, text_data):
        print(text_data)
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'status': 'We Got You'}))

    def disconneted(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("disconnected")

    def send_notification(self, event):
        print('Send Notification: ')
        data = json.loads(event.get('value'))
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'status': data}))

        print('Send Notification: ')
```

asgi.py

```
"""
ASGI config for hamza project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from bilal.consumers import TestConsumer
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'hamza.settings')

asgiapplication = get_asgi_application()

ws_pattern = [
    path('ws/test/', TestConsumer.as_asgi())
]

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': URLRouter(ws_pattern)
})
```

[image: You Can Check The Image Of Webscoketking]